# Preloading image on next page in lightbox

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, preload

I am using a lightbox in my react app (displays an image in a modal, user can go to next image by hitting right arrow key).

The problem is that whenever a user goes to the next image, it takes a second for the  tag to make the request to load the image. I would like to pre-load the next image before the user gets to it.

All of the image URLs are fetched at once in the parent component, so I have all of the image urls.

Does anyone know of a way I can pre-load the image so it doesn't have to take the second to fetch and render?

Comment: an old way was to put those image into a background of an element  with no-repeat and at a position outside of the area shown by that element. So they are load by the style sheet, but unseen . How ever, it takes time to load all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if I understood correctly what solution you would like, but you could use.

If you want to have a look: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

which is specifically made for use cases like masonry plugin layouts, to check if all images have finished loading and then execute functions / other scripts.

Example:

```
$('#your-container').imagesLoaded( {
  },
   function() {
   $('a.gallery').featherlight({
   targetAttr: 'href'
  });
  }
 );
```

I hope it helps a little.